# How to detect NSManagedObject is loaded complete?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

How to detect NSManagedObject is loaded complete?

I need to do something when NSManagedObject is loaded, for example a software start up completed.
I need to refer to data of NSManagedObject for doing something actions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean "NSManagedObject is loaded"?

Comment: for example : 
I have an attribute called folder and a collectFilesInFolder method  in NSManagedObject

If I call setFolder: method will invoke collectFilesInFolder. <- OK

But I encountered a problem If my software start up ready, How to invoke collectFilesInFolder method auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not quite clear, however for a quick answer, there are two points of view:

- For a single NSManagedObject awakeFromFetch should suit your needs.
- Or you could refer to the NSManagedObjectContext notification, altough this is more related to save/update/delete operation

Otherwise, explain better what you need.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, The first one is fit to me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't understand why the awakeFromFetch called twice? one time for  software start up. one time for invoke folder(getter) method.